# Parse user data in to student and teacher details

Tags: javascript, performance

Initially I have a code in `JavaScript` which looks like -

```
const createUsersInfo = obj => {
    const studentDetails = [];
    const teacherDetails = [];
    obj.forEach(x => {
      if (x.type) {
        if ( x.type === 'teacher' && x.group !== 'admin' ) {
            teacherDetails.push(x);
        } else if ( x.type === 'student' && x.group !== 'admin' ) {
            studentDetails.push(x);
        }
      }
    });

    return {
        studentDetails,
        teacherDetails
    };
};
```

Then, I refactored it to -

```
const createUsersInfo = obj => {
  const studentDetails = [];
  const teacherDetails = [];
  obj.forEach(x => {
    const type = x.type;
    if ( type && x.group !== 'admin' ) {
      if ( type === 'teacher' ) {
        teacherDetails.push(x);
      }
      if ( type === 'student' ) {
        studentDetails.push(x);
      }
    }
  });

  return {
    studentDetails,
    teacherDetails
  };
};
```

Is this better as compared to my initial version or it can  further improved ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. If you have a new question, post a new question with a link back to this one instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short review;

- You can avoid process typeless and admin users by using an upfront `.filter()`
- `obj` is a terrible name (it implies the parameter is just an `Object` instead of an `Array`, `list` would be better, something meaningful like `userDetails` the best
- If you want to go for slightly less efficient code, you could replace the whole loop with 2 filters
- Dont go for fat arrow syntax unless you are coding and inline function

I would go for something like this;

```
function createUsersInfo(userDetails){
  const cleanUserDetails = userDetails.filter(user => (user.type && user.group != 'admin'));
  return {
    studentDetails: cleanUserDetails.filter(user => user.type === 'student'),
    teacherDetails: cleanUserDetails.filter(user => user.type === 'teacher')
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Yes, I totally agree with you on the naming convention side but I believe replacing `forEach` and `if` statements with 3 `filter()` will might impact performance (at least theoritically)

Comment: I tried an implementation using `reducer()` function, please have a look at it well.